# Detect the Serializer being used in an Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I switched to Ember-Cli from a plain old Ember application.

The problem is that my models are not being properly serialized.

How can I debug all the serializers to see what is going on? 
- The application serializer 
- The adapter serializer 
- The model serializer

Can I for example do this with a console.log in my custom adapter's createRecord() function?

Comment: Highly recommend the Ember Inspector plugin for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Steve H. but how can I use the Ember Inspector for Chrome to debug the serializers?

Comment: Well, you don't need the Ember Inspector to do that, the Chrome debugger is already there (if you're using Chrome, Firebug is an equivalent for Firefox, but I debug only with Chrome).  Have you tried debugging using the Chrome debugger?  Setting breakpoints in your serializers?